# Importing and using custom font is not working

Tags: flutter

I am using Android Studio as my IDE. Now, I am trying to use custom fonts. But my code is not working. Here is what I have done so far. I download the fonts from the fonts.google.com and imported the `TTF` files into my project creating a new folder called fonts right under my project root folder.

[image]

Then I added the following code to my pubspec.yml file.

```
fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 400
```

Then I set the custom font to the Text widget as follows.

```
Text("Flight", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),)
```

When I launch the app, it does not work. The font is not changed. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the code in pubspec.yml, you should run `flutter pub get` in the terminal. This command gets all the dependencies listed in the pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and run:

flutter clean

flutter pub get